# Where is turtledemo in the python3 libraries?

Tags: python

I can't seem to find the [turtledemo](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.6/Lib) package in the python3 distribution on my ubuntu installation (`/usr/lib/python3.6/`).  Does ubuntu remove it for some reason?  If so, how to I get it back?

python3.6
ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Does this help: `sudo apt-get install python3.6-examples` ?

Comment: @andrew.46 that has done it.

Comment: Great! I have made a formal answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Python package is a little split up, the following should make the [turtledemo](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/python3.6-examples/filelist) available again:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-examples
```

And then all should be well :)

Comment: At least with python3.8, you have to ALSO install `idle-python3.8` or the turtledemo will crash with an error from trying to use module `idlelib.colorizer` which is not present.  Not sure where to report this as a dependency bug.

Comment: same with python 3.6 - you also need to install `idle-python3.6` to get the menu program